# Getting modified occurrance for series event using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm subscribing to calendar event changes **using webhook API**:

```
GraphAPI.api('subscriptions')
.post({
    changeType: 'created,updated,deleted',
    notificationUrl: 'https://www.example.com/callback/newevent',
    resource: `users/user@example.com/calendar/events`,
    expirationDateTime: moment().add(expireInMinutes, 'minutes').toDate(),
    clientState: 'subscription-identifier'
}, (err, res) => {
    // ...
})
```

This works really well.
When I create a recurring event, I get the `type: 'seriesMaster'` property which make sense.

However, **if I delete or modify an occurrence, I still get the seriesMaster event and not the occurrence I modified**.

Here's the resource returned to my webhook:

```
[ { subscriptionId: '12345-sub-id',
    subscriptionExpirationDateTime: '2018-02-15T01:28:52.836+00:00',
    changeType: 'updated',
    resource: 'Users/12345-user-id/Events/12345-event-id',
    resourceData:
     { '@odata.type': '#Microsoft.Graph.Event',
       '@odata.id': 'Users/12345-user-id/Events/12345-event-id',
       '@odata.etag': 'W/"12345-tag-id"',
       id: '12345-event-id' },
    clientState: 'subscription-identifier' } ]
```

Getting the event id, we get the series master:

```
{ '@odata.context': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(\'user@example.com\')/calendar/events/$entity',
  '@odata.etag': 'W/"12345-etag-val"',
  id: '12345-event-id',
  createdDateTime: '2018-02-14T21:20:47.7698185Z',
  lastModifiedDateTime: '2018-02-15T01:27:00.3099975Z',
  changeKey: '12345-etag-val',
  categories: [],
  originalStartTimeZone: 'Mountain Standard Time',
  originalEndTimeZone: 'Mountain Standard Time',
  iCalUId: '12345-icaluid',
  reminderMinutesBeforeStart: 15,
  isReminderOn: true,
  hasAttachments: false,
  subject: 'test 201802141420',
  bodyPreview: 'testing',
  importance: 'normal',
  sensitivity: 'normal',
  isAllDay: false,
  isCancelled: false,
  isOrganizer: false,
  responseRequested: true,
  seriesMasterId: null,
  showAs: 'tentative',
  type: 'seriesMaster',
  ...
}
```

So, how do I get the modified/deleted occurrence of an event in this case?

Answer (score 0):

That's tricky, there's no real cut-and-dry way to do this that covers all scenarios. This is because the only items that actually exist are the series masters, occurrences are all derived from that.

Basically what you can do is expand the `instances` property on the event, but you have to provide a start and end time to give bounds on how far the server will expand.

So if you know the start and end dates of the recurrence pattern (assuming there IS an end date!), you can expand all the instances. You'd then have to compare that to what you had before to figure out which specific instance changed.

Comment: The other issues is that it's not even clear if `seriesMaster` or an `occurrence` has changed.